# Integration with x in the bounds

Tags: calculus, integration

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWsG0.png

This is the question and this is the answer I got using FTC

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLPrX.png

I'm not quite sure why that's wrong and what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Type the question instead of providing links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your answer is a sum of two terms.

the exact answer consists only of the

first one.

we just use the derivative of the composition

$(fog)'(x)=f'(g(x)).g'(x)$

and FTIC :

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xF(t)dt=F(x)$.